# PHP Libraries - what are they and how to create one

Tags: php, c, dll, libraries

1) Is a PHP library (as in the GD Library) a compiled DLL (or other appropriate name if that is not used outside of Windows) written in a language such as C, compiled, and then "loaded" and made available to PHP code?

2) If this is the case, where can I find documentation on libraries which, among other things, includes calling, argument passing, and value return standards and protocals, and other information which I can use to get started writing PHP  "libraries"? I am not looking for documentation on how to program in C or another language, I am looking only for specific, and detailed, information on creating "libraries" for PHP.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

1. In the php world I believe it's called an extension and it's behave similar to a windows dll and maybe has something similar when you want to create one.
2. theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/zend.php. I think its part of the php documentation, the url www.php net may work also.

Comment: That for the reply, I'll look at those pages. By the way, I think I misread the "dll" thing - what I'm now reading talks about using dl() to load the extension when the script is run.--------------------- remainder of this comment is below in my other comment-------------------

Comment: oops - hit enter...... while typing the comment ---- is there any way to get a blank line in comments? I am in the habit of inserting white space in text to make it easier to use and I habitually do so by pressing Enter twice. However, here it posts the comment instead.----As I was saying, it appears extensions can be loaded at run time or also loaded via PHP.ini, problem there is that if it isn't your server, you might not be able to talk them into it.

Comment: No, you can't add blank lines to a comment. I suppose you mean this: http://blog.hardkap.com/index.php/posts/00057/Load-a-PHP-extension-at-runtime? It's true that you need a server but you can rent a virtual server very cheap.